# ng-options inside ng-repeat removing already selected values of options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Simple problem, but I'm not sure how to solve it.

I have ng-repeat that create select boxes dinamically with ng-options of the same value

I have ng-repeat, that iterate model option.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="condition in model.conditions">
    <label>{{condition}}</label>
    <select data-ng-model="selectedValue"
            ng-options="item.name for item in optionList">
    </select>
</div>
```

this is the condition model:

```
$scope.model = 
    {
        conditions:
        [
            {id:1,name:"CONDITION_ONE"},
            {id:2,name:"CONDITION_TWO"}
        ]
    }
```

this is the optionList item:

```
$scope.optionList = 
    [
        {id:1, name:"OPTION_ONE"},
        {id:2, name:"OPTION_TWO"},
        {id:3, name:"OPTION_Three"}
    ];
```

**Merely illustrative image:**

[image]

What I'm trying to do is, when selecting an item in the select box from above, I would like to remove this item from the select box from below and thus, **preventing duplicate items by removing already selected items**.

Is there any way can I do this using angularJS?

Comment: Remove the option `Array.filter()` from optionList every time the user selects a value. If you need the original as well, just clone it at the start so you have one filtered copy to render and one master copy containing all the possible options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the filter in ng-repeat

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div data-ng-repeat="condition in model.conditions">
    <label>Remove Id {{condition.id}} from  List </label>
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="item.name for item in filter(condition)">
</select>

</div></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.optionList = 
    [
        {id:1, name:"OPTION_ONE"},
        {id:2, name:"OPTION_TWO"},
        {id:3, name:"OPTION_Three"}
    ];
    
    $scope.model = 
    {
        videos:
        [
            {id:1,name:"CONDITION_ONE"},
            {id:2,name:"CONDITION_TWO"}
        ],
        conditions : [
        {id:1, name:"OPTION_ONE"},
        {id:2, name:"OPTION_TWO"},
        {id:3, name:"OPTION_Three"}
    ]
    };
    
    $scope.filter = (item)=>{
     return $scope.optionList.filter(list => list.id !== item.id);
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```